# Removing "3D look" from Delphi controls

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Standard Delphi controls (panels, buttons etc.) all have this bevel effect (white line on top and on the left) that gives them a 3D feel but today it makes them look old fashioned.

Is there a way to remove this "3D look" at least in Delphi 7?

Comment: Upgrade to a version of Delphi that's newer than a decade ago? :-)

Answer (score 4):

Some controls have a `Ctl3D` property that you can turn off.

For a `TPanel`, you can also turn off its `Bevel...` properties.

What you really should do instead is enable Visual Styles in your app so it has a themed look on Windows XP and later.  Delphi 7 did not natively support Visual Styles, but you can use Mike Lischke's [XP Theme Manager](http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php/controls/windows-xp-theme-manager) component to handle that (it was incorporated directly into later VCL versions).